# How can I change the service reference address?

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, deployment

I've created a silverlight application that uses a service. On my dev machine everything works well. I was able to discover and add the service without any problems.

I then published the application and my silverlight app became inresponsive. After some searching my silverlight app reference the service as `http://localhost:50453/SilverlightService.svc` and that is not true for my productionmachin as it runs on port 80.

How can I change this? I've tried to change the address, but then VS cant find it and does not allow me to change it

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at web.config transforms.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_webdevelopment_topic4.aspx